# Session is reset after redirect from Apple

Tags: php, apache, session-cookies

I'm implementing sign in with apple, the technology they use is some form of oauth2. I create a secure link and send the user to that link where user enters their apple account details and allows sign in. Once that is done, apple returns the user to my website but the problem is, that request does not contain the PHPSESSID cookie.

PHP thus creates a new one and I've lost session data that I need to complete the login process. I've tried setting up the session cookie options but haven't been able to succeed. here are my current settings:

[image: PHP Info]

I've tried Lax and None as the samesite value but nothing is making a difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing the session ID in the URL or something? That generally isn't a good way to do it. Normally the browser caches a session cookie related to a particular domain, and sends it whenever it needs to make a request to that domain (for the duration of the browser session, unless some additional persistence mechanism is used).

Comment: Are you saying that your existing session gets removed after you've called the Oauth2 server, or are you expecting to get a PHPSESSID from the Oauth2 server? Please clarify the issue and expectations by sharing the relevant code and explain the flow, both what you expect and what currently happens.

Comment: So are you trying to set up session cookies in order to remedy this situation, and failing? Is that the issue? What specific issue is occuring when you use this setup? Are there some errors? Or unexpected behaviour? Try to be specific. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see that the samesite setting (https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-samesite) would have any effect on your scenario since it doesn't sound like you would be doing any cross-domain AJAX requests.

Comment: @ADyson SameSite is not _just_ about cross-origin background requests, whether cookies will be sent when the user explicitly "navigates" between origins, can also be affected.

Comment: _"I've tried Lax and None as the samesite value but nothing is making a difference."_ - did you verify those changes actually took effect? Did you verify this with a _new_ session?

Comment: @CBroe I see, I wasn't aware of that subtlety, thanks. Do you happen to know if it would come into play in the OP's specific scenario, then?

Comment: @ADyson it should come into play, in the scenario of going from their site, to Apple's, and back to theirs. But `None` should allow the cookies to be send in _all_ possible scenarios already, and if SameSite was not specified at all, it should default to `Lax` in current browsers, which should also make the client send the cookie in this scenario.

Comment: @ADyson I'm not passing any session id, I'm saving a key to $_SESSION that is needed after the user comes back from Apple. This is how the process is supposed to be,

Comment: @M.Eriksson Correct. I'm inspecting cookies from the developer tools. The PHPSESSID cookie is not sent when the user is redirected back to my site and php creates a new session.

Comment: @CBroe Yes the phpinfo page does show the relevant changes

Note that apple sends a post request back if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you sure? Redirecting the browser back to your site via a link which the browser executes would always have to be a GET, not a POST. Unless their site is using some JS to execute a cross-origin POST...but that would be an odd way to do it, I think. Is there some Apple documentation you can refer us to which describes what you're expecting to happen?

Comment: Are you sure you have started the session before trying to read/write to it? There is nothing about the flow itself that should be able to cause this. Without seeing how you actually have implemented it, we can't really know what's going on. Please read my first comment and update your question with all the needed info.

Comment: I don't see anything in the explanation in the MDN, that the request method should make a difference; although the term "navigation" used there is a bit ambiguous. Chromium had an "extension" to how the treat Lax and POST requests for a while to fix issues resulting from something being limited, https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/AknSSyQTGYs/m/wRWG65IWBQAJ - not sure if that is still the case though.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Apache/PHP sets the session cookie lifetime to 0 which is equivalent to 'as long the session is active'. When the user closes the tab (all tabs of the domain), the cookie is invalidated. This is what was happening in my case. As the user leaves the site to go to Apple's, the cookie is no longer valid. When the user is returned back, the cookie is not sent.

To remedy the situation I've set `session.cookie_lifetime = 600`. It works now. I've restored the other settings to default. This is how my settings look like now.

[image: Php info]

Comment: Are you sure? Normally that wouldn't apply unless they actually closed the whole browser. Which browser(s) have you tested with?

Comment: I'm using MS Edge

Comment: If you're going to investigate an issue like this, at the very least you need to test it in several browsers (in case the issue is browser-specific). :-)

Comment: Does Chrome behave differently in this situation? That would be surprising to me. I don't have it installed atm.

Comment: Not just Chrome (that's the least likely, since Edge uses the Chromium engine too). But also Firefox, Opera, Safari (if you have an apple device handy), mobile browsers etc. That would be a comprehensive test, and allow you to be sure that the issue does indeed relate to PHP config and/or the Apple redirect code, and isn't a browser-specific problem.